# Why i can't use equals for BigInteger and int?

Tags: java, int, bigint

When i try to compare `BigInteger` and `int`:

```
 BigInteger balance = new BigInteger(out_str.substring(186, 201).trim());
 if (!balance.equals(0)) {...}
```

I get:

> equals () between objects of inconvertible types 'int' and 'BigInteger'

Comment: `BigInteger` is an object (with methods and class variables and all that stuff), `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: Use this: `if (!balance.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` and `BigInteger` don't share any class as `int` is a **primitive type**.

You can only compare stuff which has at least **something in common**, like `Object`. So a comparison like `BigInteger` with the wrapper class `Integer` would compile, but the result would be `false` since an `Integer` is no `BigInteger`. You will need to **transform** your `int` to a `BigInteger` for comparison.

For `0` there is the **constant** `BigInteger.ZERO` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ZERO)):

```
if (!balance.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does "you can only compare stuff which has at least something in common" mean?

Comment: @Kayaman If you look at the class hierarchy of both objects, there must be a common type. This is true for all *objects* since they always implicitly are of type `Object` at least. However **primitive types** are not of type `Object`, thus they are not comparable. But yeah, my formulation is **vague**. Feel free to edit the answer if you have a better formulation :)

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't create classes `A` and `B` that don't share a superclass, but can be compared with `equals()`. A common superclass is not a requirement, but it can be advantageous (such as with `Number`).

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
if (!balance.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
    ...
}
```